# Mapping Multiple tables to Single Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design

I have a Database that contains multiple tables which are generated on a per month basis. e.g

```
Transaction_01_2014
Transaction_02_2014
Transaction_03_2014
.
.
.
Transaction_12_2014
```

All the tables have the same structure. The only difference is the month and year appended at the end.

Is it possible to map all these tables to a single @Entity class "Transaction" in Hibernate? if yes, do I need to change some configurations? If its not possible this way, how should I operate on these tables in an subtle and simple manner, from my java application?

Cheers!

Comment: How would u want to map ur tables with Entity (XML or Annotation) ?

Comment: I would go for Annotation

Comment: Have a look at my answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** You can map multiple tables to a single @Entity class using **@MappedSuperclass annotation**. By creating a super with this annotation & inheriting it's feature to all sub-classes with different tables in @Table annotation. **But, in this case problem of normalization arises**.

**OR**

You can use **@SecondaryTable annotation** which allows you to specify one or more secondary tables indicating that the data for the entity class is stored across multiple tables.

**For more information :**

1. [@MappedSuperclass - Java Doc Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)
2. [@SecondaryTable - Java Doc Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html)
3. [Tutorial - Map One POJO To Multiple Tables](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/MapOnePOJOToMultipleTables.htm)

Comment: Yeah exactly... Why don't you go with single table & perform per month basis operations ?

Comment: Hey, u can **use @ SecondaryTable instead of @ MappedSuperclass annotation**. I have updated my answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks alot for the suggestion but i have to deal with DB as it is, and there is a monthly table upto five years. Hence I cannot create secondary 12 X 5 table classes/entities.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of this new entity is to **read** and **not for insert, update and delete**, like reporting and monitoring then following the approach may help you:

1. You may create a database VIEW that unions-all these tables.
2. Having the new @Entity class mapped to these VIEW will solve the problem.
3. The View's definition(DDL) needs to be updated by a database job
   (side by side of tables generation per month )